# How do I split 1 table into 2 parts, such as my emp table salary > 2000 and the other part salary < 2000?

Tags: apache-pig

I have a emp table Alias (Z) which consists of 4 columns, ename, deptno, sal, and deptno. Is there a way I can get the table to display 2 parts. One with sal > 2000 and the other with sal < 2000. Is there a single line syntax for this or would I have to just execute each line individually?

I tried T = FILTER Z by (sal > 2000) or (sal < 2000); but this doesn't display what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind I found the answer. SPLIT Z into emp1 if sal<2000, emp2 if sal>=2000;